# CodeIgniter dbcollat

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli

I am using CodeIgniter with the following settings:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8'; 
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

My database columns and table use `utf8_unicode_ci` as the collation. Should I change how I connect?

What potential problems are there if I don't change. The application seems to be working fine now, but I just noticed this discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what exactly are the potential problems. In general, when application setup does not match the database encoding setup, an encoding problem occurs (displaying, sorting, filtering, searching). One thing is certain - once you will stumble into an encoding problem, you will begin with changing the CI setup to match the DB setup, or opposite.

The difference between both collations is explained in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).
There's also a blog-post by Phil Sturgeon in regards to [UTF-8 support for CodeIgniter](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/08/UTF-8-support-for-CodeIgniter).

So yes, you should change how you connect.